# Solve $X^3 = A$ in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ where the matrix $A$ is given.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Consider the matrix:

$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -2 \\
6 & -4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I have to solve the equation:

$$X^3 = A$$

where $X \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

First, I tried using the notation:

$$X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$. I raised $X$ to the third power and then equated it with $A$ hoping to get something nice. Surprise, surprise, I didn't.

Then I noticed that the determinant of $A$ is $0$ and since $X^3 = A$, that means that the determinant of $X$ is also $0$. So we have the relation:

$$ad = bc$$

in the matrix $X$. But I don't see how I could use this further or even if I should at all.

So how should I approach this exercise?

Comment: I noticed that $A^3=A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$A$ has two eigenvalues $\lambda_1=0$ ($\because \det(A)=0$) and $\lambda_2=-1$ ($\because \text{tr}(A)=-4+3=-1 =\text{sum of eigenvalues}$).

So $A$ is diagonalizable, i.e. we can write $A=P\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}=PDP^{-1}$.

Note that $\sqrt[3]{D}=D$ itself. So we can have $X=PDP^{-1}=A$.

**Another way**
Observe that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^2+\lambda=0$. Thus $A^2+A=0$. Which means $A^3=A$.

Comment: “at the very least” meaning there could be other solutions as well?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner After your comment, I noticed that OP only wants real matrices. Otherwise $\omega A$ and $\omega^2A$ can also be candidates.

Comment: @AnuragA Can you please explain why is it that $\sqrt[3]D = D$?

Comment: @user1502 For a diagonal matrix $D$, to obtain $D^k$ all you need is to raise each of the diagonal entry to the $k^{\text{th}}$ power. So ask yourself, which diagonal $\begin{bmatrix}s&0\\0&t\end{bmatrix}$matrix should we start with such that it's cube is $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 0):

$A=uv^T=\pmatrix{1\\ 2}\pmatrix{3&-2}$ is a rank-one matrix. Therefore $X$ (if exists) must have rank one. It follows that $X$ and $A$ have the same column spaces and the row spaces, i.e. $X=cA$ for some scalar $c$. The equation $A=X^3$ thus reduces to $A=c^3A^3=c^3(v^Tu)^2A=c^3A$ or $c^3=1$. As $X$ is real, $c=1$. Hence $X=A$ is the only solution.